# In the making of Blue Eye Samurai, what software was used, how many people participated, and how long did it take?

Tags: anime-production, blue-eye-samurai

In November 2023, Netflix began streaming Blue Eye Samurai. What software was used to make it, how many people did it, and how long did it take to produce it?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This show was made by French studio Blue Spirit who uses Autodesk Maya.

Comment: maya is a modeling software, but what software does animation do?

Comment: Maya is also industry standard for rigging/animation.